# Plotly - hovertemplate two columns

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, hover

How to format the hover template to align the second column, please? Spacing is not enough as you can see in figure.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

r = np.random.RandomState(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        **{"x": np.linspace(0, 1, 10), "y": r.uniform(8, 9, 10)},
        **{c: r.uniform(i, i + 1, 10) for i, c in enumerate("ABCDE")},
    }
)

fig = px.scatter(df, x="x", y="y", hover_data={c: True for c in df.columns})

fig.update_traces(
    hovertemplate="<br>".join(
        [
            "<b>TT:</b>                              %{customdata[0]}",
            "<b>A: </b>                              %{x:.3f} deg",
            "<b>CCCCC: </b>                    %{y:.3f} deg<extra></extra>",  # extra delete the name next to the hover
            "<b>K: </b>                              %{customdata[2]:.3f} deg",
            "<b>LLLLLLLLLLLLLL:</b>   %{customdata[1]:.3f} deg",
        ]
    )
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Have created MWE.
- use none breaking spaces
- use fixed width font

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# construct figure for MWE
r = np.random.RandomState(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        **{"x": np.linspace(0, 1, 10), "y": r.uniform(8, 9, 10)},
        **{c: r.uniform(i, i + 1, 10) for i, c in enumerate("ABCDE")},
    }
)

fig = px.scatter(df, x="x", y="y", hover_data={c: True for c in df.columns})

# use none breaking spaces and fixed width font
fig.update_traces(
    hovertemplate="<br>".join(
        [
            s.replace(" ", "&nbsp;")
            for s in [
                "<b>TT:</b>               %{customdata[0]}",
                "<b>A: </b>               %{x:.3f} deg",
                "<b>CCCCC: </b>           %{y:.3f} deg<extra></extra>",  # extra delete the name next to the hover
                "<b>K: </b>               %{customdata[2]:.3f} deg",
                "<b>LLLLLLLLLLLLLL:</b>   %{customdata[1]:.3f} deg",
            ]
        ]
    )
).update_layout(hoverlabel_font_family="Courier")
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, I provided the wrong example. Variables are not of the same length. I corrected that. I called bold and unbold part as two columns.